# What is the value of beta distribution at $x=0$, when $\alpha, \beta < 1$?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, beta-function

I am a bit confused as to how the beta distribution can be defined at $0$. The formulation of the beta distribution is given as -

$f(x)=\frac{\Gamma(a+b)}{\Gamma(\alpha) \Gamma(\beta)} x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}$,     for $0 \le x \le 1$  
          $=0$,                                               otherwise

If I use $\alpha = \beta = 0.5$, at $x=0$ the beta distribution would have a term $0^{-0.5}$. Does this not give $\infty$ at $x=0,1$? Can we safely deal with distribution functions having such singularities in their domain?

Besides, what might the interpretation be of such infinities when $\text{Beta}(0.5, 0.5)$ is used as a Bayesian prior? The $\alpha$, $\beta$ in the prior distribution are often interpreted as number of successes and failures previously seen; hence form the basis of our prior belief. In this context, how can $\text{Beta}(0.5, 0.5)$ assign the highest probability density to the extremes $x=0,1$?

---

**What I found till now:**

There are a few resources where the domain has been restricted to $0 < x < 1$. But a clear indication of the motivation has not been provided. For example, the Wikipedia article on [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Definitions) provides both closed and open domains as options.
Although in the same article, [the section on mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Mode), does point to the issue of a singularity at $x=0,1$ when $\alpha, \beta < 1$. It does not, however, speak of any appropriate method to deal with this, or interpret it.